# How to enable authentication for mongo db and connect with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am new to Mongo DB, and I didn't find any good resource/example for that. What I'd like to achieve is have a MongoDB running on my server, with authentication turned on. And a database for my application, with a user who can access the data.

I have mongo up and running and now try to connect to the db:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      port: 27017
      host: <host name>
      database: test
```

But I get connection refused all the time.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of resources including a getting started guide on the Spring web site. The MongoDB documentation has detailed instructions on how to add users and enable authentication. The Spring Boot reference documentation describes how to configure the mongodb connection, including credentials.

But your output above says "Connection refused". 
So either your mongodb isn't actually up and running, or your configuration points to the wrong server. Double check the host name (which you decided to hide in your question), and log on to the mongodb server and check that the `mongod` process is actually running. Then you can continue to work on the authentication.